# How to uniformly use a texture without uv unwrapping?

Tags: materials

I'm trying to use a nylon texture on a cushion-like object and when I unwrap it, it warps the texture.  Is there a way to have the nylon work in a naturally procedural fashion that doesn't warp around corners and crevices?

Here's what it looks like without the material:

[image]

Here's with the material:

[image]

This is my node setup for the material:

[image]

Eventually, I would like to be able to make straps like this:

[image]

Comment: Either properly unwrap your object so there is no warping, or use procedural texture coordinates like *Object* or *Generated*

Comment: Ah yes!  Generated did the trick.  So amazingly simple.  Thanks